# Oracle job queue

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть `job`, который запускает процедуру с входящими параметрами через программу. Как запустить  `job` вовремя ее выполнения чтобы она стала в очередь и начала отрабатывать после завершения первой, но уже с другими параметрами?

`job` запускаю след образом

```
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('GPIMS.JOB_UPD_GP_ADDR_MAPP',1,IN_GP_ID);
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('GPIMS.JOB_UPD_GP_ADDR_MAPP',2,to_char(P_GP_STATUS_DATE));
dbms_scheduler.enable('GPIMS.JOB_UPD_GP_ADDR_MAPP');
```

Создание `job`

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job('GPIMS.JOB_UPD_GP_ADDR_MAPP',
                            program_name                => 'GPIMS.PROGRAM_UPD_GP_ADDR_MAPP',
                            auto_drop                   => FALSE);
end;
```

Создание программы

```
begin
  sys.dbms_scheduler.create_program(program_name        => 'GPIMS.PROGRAM_UPD_GP_ADDR_MAPP',
                                    program_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
                                    program_action      => 'GPIMS.PKG_GLOBAL_PROBLEM.UPD_GP_ADDR_MAPP',
                                    number_of_arguments => 3,
                                    enabled             => false,
                                    comments            => '');
  sys.dbms_scheduler.define_program_argument(program_name        => 'GPIMS.PROGRAM_UPD_GP_ADDR_MAPP',
                                             argument_position   => 1,
                                             argument_name       => 'IN_GP_ID',
                                             argument_type       => 'VARCHAR2',
                                             default_value       => '');
  sys.dbms_scheduler.define_program_argument(program_name        => 'GPIMS.PROGRAM_UPD_GP_ADDR_MAPP',
                                             argument_position   => 2,
                                             argument_name       => 'P_GP_STATUS_DATE',
                                             argument_type       => 'DATE',
                                             default_value       => '');
  sys.dbms_scheduler.define_program_argument(program_name        => 'GPIMS.PROGRAM_UPD_GP_ADDR_MAPP',
                                             argument_position   => 3,
                                             argument_name       => 'OUT_MSG',
                                             argument_type       => 'VARCHAR2',
                                             default_value       => '');
  sys.dbms_scheduler.enable(name => 'GPIMS.PROGRAM_UPD_GP_ADDR_MAPP');
end;
```

Comment: А какие у вас сложности возникли?  К чему привела попытка - `dbms_scheduler.run ()`?

Comment: @0xdb сложность в том что job нельзя было добавить в очередь методом описанным выше, если job уже был запущен

Comment: Правильно, я это и разяснил в ответе. Указали бы это раньше в вопросе - желаемый результат, и что не получается - сразу бы получили бы решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так нельзя делать. Невозможно запустить *once Job*, который уже выполняется.
Для этого есть цепочки (*job chains*), но передать к каждому звену цепочки свои параметры также не представляется возможным.

Можно передать каждому звену мета данные, например: `job_name, job_subname`, как формальные параметры. Они будут замещены актуальными значениями для выполняемой задачи и соответственно звена задачи. Далее определить эти же данные как ключ в таблице для параметров.

Подготовим схему:

```
create table myJobInfo (beg timestamp, end timestamp, info varchar2 (256));
create or replace type myJobArgs as object (
    jobName varchar2 (32), jobStepName varchar2 (32), argChar varchar2 (64), argDate date);
/
create table myJobArgsTab of myJobArgs;
insert into myJobArgsTab
    select myJobArgs (
        'myJob', 'chainStep'||rownum, 'arg char '||rownum, date'2018-07-01'+(rownum-1)) 
    from xmlTable ('1 to 3');
```

Создадим программу и цепочку выполненения, которая будет запускать эту программу в каждом звене:

```
begin
    sys.dbms_scheduler.create_program (
        program_name=>'myJobProg', 
        program_type=>'stored_procedure',
        program_action=>'myJobProc',
        number_of_arguments=>2,
        enabled=>false,
        comments=>'test job')
        ;
    dbms_scheduler.define_metadata_argument (
        program_name=>'myJobProg',
        metadata_attribute=>'job_name',
        argument_position=>1
        );
    dbms_scheduler.define_metadata_argument (
        program_name=>'myJobProg',
        metadata_attribute=>'job_subname',
        argument_position=>2
        );
    sys.dbms_scheduler.enable ('myJobProg');
    -- create chain/steps 
    dbms_scheduler.create_chain ('myJobChain');
    dbms_scheduler.define_chain_step ('myJobChain', 'chainStep1', 'myJobProg');
    dbms_scheduler.define_chain_step ('myJobChain', 'chainStep2', 'myJobProg');
    dbms_scheduler.define_chain_step ('myJobChain', 'chainStep3', 'myJobProg');
    -- rules
    dbms_scheduler.define_chain_rule ('myJobChain', condition=>'true', action=>'start chainStep1');
    dbms_scheduler.define_chain_rule ('myJobChain', condition=>'chainStep1 completed', action=>'start chainStep2');
    dbms_scheduler.define_chain_rule ('myJobChain', condition=>'chainStep2 completed', action=>'start chainStep3');
    dbms_scheduler.define_chain_rule ('myJobChain', condition=>'chainStep3 completed', action=>'end');
    dbms_scheduler.enable ('myJobChain');
end;
/
```

Тест процедура:

```
create or replace procedure myJobProc (jobName varchar2, jobStepName varchar2) is
    rowid_ rowid;
    args myJobArgs;
begin 
    begin 
        select value (t) into args
        from myJobargsTab t
        where upper (t.jobName)     = myJobProc.jobName 
        and   upper (t.jobStepName) = myJobProc.jobStepName
        for update
        ;
    exception when others then  
        dbms_output.put_line ('ERROR: '||jobName||'.'||JobStepName||': sqlerrm:'||sqlerrm);
    end;
    insert into myJobInfo (beg, info) values (
        systimestamp, jobName||'.'||JobStepName||': args='||args.argChar||'/'||to_char (args.argDate,'yyyy-mm-dd'))
    returning rowid into rowid_
    ;
    sys.dbms_lock.sleep (3);
    update myJobInfo set end=systimestamp where rowid=rowid_;
end;
/
```

Запустим всю цепочку и посмотрим, что получилось:

```
exec dbms_scheduler.run_chain (chain_name=>'myJobChain', start_steps=>null, job_name=>'myJob');

select * from myJobInfo order by beg desc;

BEG          END          INFO                                                           
------------ ------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------
10:52:24.246 10:52:27.246 MYJOB.CHAINSTEP3: args=arg char 3/2018-07-03                    
10:52:21.202 10:52:24.202 MYJOB.CHAINSTEP2: args=arg char 2/2018-07-02                    
10:52:18.154 10:52:21.154 MYJOB.CHAINSTEP1: args=arg char 1/2018-07-01
```

Для дальнейшей информации читаем оф. документацию [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/scheduling-jobs-with-oracle-scheduler.html#GUID-D41660D0-D88F-4D9F-8CC8-63D040EDC4E6) и [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html#GUID-A24DEB5D-2EAF-4C0B-8715-30DC947B3F87).

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/857555/201383, но все оказалось немного проще. Получилось сделать с помощью dbms_job.submit. Все работает как надо.

```
dbms_job.submit(l_jobno, 'declare OUT_MSG varchar2(50); BEGIN gpims.pkg_global_problem.UPD_GP_ADDR_MAPP('''||IN_GP_ID||''', '''||P_GP_STATUS_DATE||''', OUT_MSG); END;');
```

Comment: dbms_job объявлен устаревшим. Некоторые DBA выключают его уже в текуших релизах. Обратитесь к ним, до того, как запустите ваше решение в продуктивной среде.

Comment: Зачем пользоваться [заведомо устаревшим методом](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/upgrd/deprecated-features-oracle-database-12c-r2.html#GUID-34F6975B-CB48-40CC-8BD8-E5386B2EADAE), который может перестать работать после обновления Oracle DB? По-моему, стоит отметить [ответ от @0xdb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/857555/211923) как правильный.